# Packing and UnPacking a float array in java

Tags: java

I have a float array `float[]x = {0.1f,0.5f,0.2f,0.3f}`. Is it possible to pack these floats into a single number and get back the floats from that number using java? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean into a single float? You'd *have* to be willing to lose information - so you need to think about what information matters to you.

Comment: Oops! I really don't want to loose information. I want to get the floats back in the order they were used before the packing

Comment: Then the answer is no. Well, I guess it could depend on what you mean by "single number", but .... no.

Comment: No. You've got 4 float values, so that's 128 bits of information. If you're happy to use a numeric type that can store 128 bits, then you can do it without losing information - but otherwise, no.

Comment: A single number meaning. An int, long or double is all valid as the type of the resultant pack.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: As Jon Skeet said, 4 floats is 128 bits (4 times the 32 bits of a float), and int, long and double are 32, 64, and 64 bits, respectively, so no, there is no numeric primitive data type in Java that can store your 4 float values without loss of information.

Comment: If all your floats have a limited range, e.g. they are all from 0.0 to 9.9 with only 1 decimal place, then yes. You can multiply them by 10 (giving integers from 0 to 99) and pack them into the digits of a long or double. If they are arbitrary float values, then no.

Comment: What do you mean by 'pack'?

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/286538). Please tell us *why* you believe you need to pack floats into a single number.

Comment: Pack to mean- Encode or compress them into a single number

Comment: @RealSkeptic I have tried with natural numbers and it works but my current code isn't working with real numbers

Comment: well, not sure what you consider a single number, but you could create a 128 bit long number to hold the 4 floats (just not a primitive in Java, e.g. `BigInteger`, `BitSet`, `ByteBuffer`!)

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Nice.. I like your idea, Yes my numbers are from 0.1 to 9.9 can you show a little example on how to get back the numbers from the resultant number.Thanks

Comment: Let's say `float[]x = {0.1f,0.5f,0.2f,0.3f}` is encoded as the `int` value `n = 1050203`. Then for example `x[2] = ((n / 10000) % 100) / 10.0f`.